# How do I list all the directories in a directory

Tags: python

I would like to know if there's a quick 1 line of code to list all the directories in a directory. It's similar to this question: [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory) , but with folders instead of files.

Comment: Recursively or just at the first level?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a recipe for just the first level:

```
dname = '/tmp'
[os.path.join(dname, d) for d in next(os.walk(dname))[1]]
```

and a recursive one:

```
dname = '/tmp'
[os.path.join(root, d) for root, dirs, _ in os.walk(dname) for d in dirs]
```

(after `import os`, obviously)

---

Note that on filesystems that support symbolic links, any *links* to directories will *not* be included here, only actual directories.

Answer (score 1):

Using os.listdir to list all the files and folders and os.path.isdir as the condition:

```
import os   
cpath = r'C:\Program Files (x86)'
onlyfolders = [f for f in os.listdir(cpath) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(cpath, f))]
```

Comment: Probably worth noting here that this _includes_ any symbolic links to directories. This behaviour contrasts with the version based on `os.walk` which I posted, which _excludes_ them. The question is not explicit about which behaviour is required, but users should be aware of the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

Import os

#use os.walk()

Example:

For folder, sub, file in os.walk(path):
Print(folder). #returns parent folder
Print (sub). #returns sub_folder
Print (file)  # returns files

Answer (score 0):

```
[ i[0] for i in os.walk('/tmp')]
```

1. here '/tmp' is the directory path for which all directories are listed
2. you need to import os

This works because i[0] gives all the root paths as it will walk through them so we don't need to do join or anything.